# MongoExport SASL authentication step: Authentication failed

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

I am having trouble running the `mongoexport` on my server in regards to the error `SASL authentication step: Authentication failed.`

The command i'm using is:

```
mongoexport --db database --collection users --out /var/www/test.json     -u username -p password --authenticationDatabase 'database'
```

I am able to get into mongo using this command:

```
mongo -u username -p password -authenticationDatabase database`
```

When I go into the user roles, my user has "ReadWrite" access.

I've tried adding role "backup" to the user, but always receive the error

```
"No role named dbAdminAnyDatabase@database"
"No role named backup@database"
```

I'm using Mongo version 3.4.6.

**Can anybody help me? What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Why did you specify both `--db` and `-d` in the command? Did you really always use `database` (in particular both for the `--authenticationDatabase` and the normal DB?

Comment: There was only type --db and -d in this example from testing purposes. I was trying different commands to see if one would work or both. They are both set with the same database --db `samename` -d `samename` I've removed the second one from the example.